# Add top shadow to TabView in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have the following:

[image]

I'm using a native `TabView`. I can change the background but I haven't been able to add a little shadow to the top of the UITabBar, I've tried creating a function and onAppear calling it like this:

```
func setupTabBar() {
//        UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(named: "tabBarBackground")
//        UITabBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = UITabBarAppearance()
    
    UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "ThemeBackground2")
    UITabBarAppearance().shadowColor = .white
}
```

which works for the background but not the top line that I need.

Here's the basic TabView:

```
TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
        MarketsTabBarView()
            .tag(HostingBarCategories.market)
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "chart.xyaxis.line")
                Text("Market")
            }
        
        PortfolioTabBarView()
            .tag(HostingBarCategories.portfolio)
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "bitcoinsign.square.fill")
                Text("Portfolio")
            }
            
        SettingsTabBarView()
            .tag(HostingBarCategories.settings)
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "gearshape.fill")
                Text("Settings")
            }
}
```

How can I add a shadow on top to mark that separetion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `shadowColor` is applied to default tab shadow which is currently absent, so we need a custom template image (eg. with gradient transparency) so `shadowColor` would tint it.

Here is working approach (Xcode 13.3 / iOS 15.4)

[image: demo]

Main part:

```
appearance.shadowColor = .white
appearance.shadowImage = UIImage(named: "tab-shadow")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
```

[Complete findings and code](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/Answers/TabBar_shadow.md)

Comment: It's really great you are posting it on github with the sample, great job and thanks

Comment: Is there a way to reduce the height of the white line? Btw this line was not needed: `appearance.shadowImage = UIImage(named: "tab-shadow")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)` I know I said shadow but I was looking for that line that separates the view from the tabbar :)

Comment: If you comment code with shadowImage you get only one white (or any color you set) line left. The observed shadow is of image height - here just for better visibility.

Comment: How would you reduce the height of that line?

Comment: btw if I put that code back I get this error: `"Need an imageRef"`